# Android Widgets - Shared preferences is not accessible

Tags: android, widget, sharedpreferences

I have a widget which takes its data from the shared preferences and displays it.
I use a configuration activity which extract the data from the shared preferences, but I noticed the context is always null while app is not in background, therefore shared preferences is not accessible. 
Is there any possibility to get the app context without the app running? or another trick to access shared prefs?

Comment: "I noticed the context is always null while app is not in background" -- your `AppWidgetProvider` gets a `Context` in its callbacks, such as [`onUpdate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider?hl=en#onUpdate(android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int%5B%5D)).

Comment: I'm not sure why but I use a static variable of context in my widget provider class.
static Context context;

But when I try to use that context its null.
Just to be clear. The widget works perfectly fine while the app is running but when I close the app process the context is null.

Comment: "But when I try to use that context its null" -- remember that your process does not live forever. So, my guess is that your process was terminated and nothing is initializing that `static` field when a fresh process is forked and your `AppWidgetProvider` is called with `onUpdate()` (or other callbacks). The simplest solution is to get rid of that `static` field and use the `Context` that is passed to the callback method.